# Laravel - Connection refused (SELECT, INSERT)

Tags: laravel

I have a program with Laravel, I made the .env configuration files to migrate the databases and it works, I created new tables and it works.

But when I do an INSERT or a SELECT it gives me connection error.

```
$dades['empleats'] = Empleats::paginate(5);
```

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `empleats`)**

The user of the database has all the permissions

What could be the problem?

Thank's

Comment: Connection refused could mean that you're either trying to connect to a remote database with a user who is only allowed to connect locally or you're trying to connect to a remote database which only allows local connections

Comment: But I was able to connect from Laravel to create the tables by migrating (with the .env file)

Answer (score 1):

Use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 (in your .env file), then run command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked

But I don’t understand what the mistake was

Comment: Laravel actually caches the config file..you can accept my answer